# Rename database dialog box within Excel-2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection, database, microsoft-excel-2016, sql

See image here>>>  **[ODBC Rename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imtNS.jpg)**

My goal is to change "User Selection for ODBC" to "Sage Login Information" or whatever. I have a few worksheets that I've setup and they all have odd names when the dialog box comes up. I know what they are but I fear other users will not know.

Is this something that has to be done under ODBC Administrator or is it done per sheet in the connection string box, with a code or something?

Any suggestions or thoughts are appreciated.
THANKS!

Comment: It might help if you identified exactly which version of Excel you are using.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  There is a tag for each version of Excel; you can use those.